# Formulating Constraints into Mixed-Integer Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Is there a way to formulate the following Linear Program in a mixed-integer LP that I could solve with most linear programs in R/Python that support Mixed Integer Linear Programs (MILP)?

So my question is: How can I use a combination of integer, binary and continuous variables to reformulate the constraints **(1)** below?

**Constants:** $C_i$ (factor exposure), $x_i^a$ (initial weight)

**Decision variables:** $x_i$ (portfolio weight)

**Portfolio Maximization:**

$\max_{x_{i}}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}\cdot C_{i}$

subject to:

**(1)** $\boldsymbol{1}_{\left\{ x_{i}\geq x_{i}^{a}\right\} }\left(x_{i}-x_{i}^{a}\right)\in\{0\}\cup\left[0.025,\infty\right],\forall i$ (Minimum purchase size of 0.025)

where

$\boldsymbol{1}_{\left\{ x_{i}\geq x_{i}^{a}\right\} }=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if  } x_{i} \geq x_{i}^{a}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Comment: did you already try something with binary variables? it seems rather standard

Comment: Hi, Yes I tried but I cannot figure out how to do it since there is a combination of semi-continous constraint (xi has to be 0 or above something), but this only for case when xi is bigger than xi^a => I only want to contraint the purchase, for a sale the ticket size doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce a small constant tolerance $\epsilon > 0$, binary decision variables $y_i^1$ and $y_i^2$, and linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_i^1 + y_i^2 &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\\
(0-x_i^a) y_i^1 + 0.025 y_i^2 \le x_i - x_i^a &\le -\epsilon y_i^1 + (1-x_i^a)y_i^2 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\\
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$ enforce $x_i - x_i^a \le -\epsilon \lor x_i - x_i^a = 0 \lor x_i - x_i^a \ge 0.025$.
Explicitly, the three cases are
\begin{align}
(y_i^1,y_i^2)=(1,0): && -x_i^a \le x_i - x_i^a &\le -\epsilon \\ 
(y_i^1,y_i^2)=(0,0): && 0 \le x_i - x_i^a &\le 0 \\ 
(y_i^1,y_i^2)=(0,1): && 0.025 \le x_i - x_i^a &\le 1-x_i^a \\ 
\end{align}

---

More simply, introduce a binary decision variable $z_i$ and linear constraints
$$-x_i^a (1-z_i) + 0.025 z_i \le x_i - x_i^a \le (1-x_i^a)z_i \text{ for all $i$}$$

If $z_i=0$, the constraint implies $-x_i^a \le x_i - x_i^a \le 0$, so $x_i \le x_i^a$.

If $z_i=1$, the constraint implies $0.025 \le x_i - x_i^a \le 1-x_i^a$, so $x_i \ge  x_i^a + 0.025$.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt! Actually I was more interested in how to solve for the first constraint in my problem. I edited the question where I only focus on (1). Do you know how would that work?

Comment: I edited my answer to match your edited question.  Just check the three cases for $(y_i^1,y_i^2)$ to see how it works.

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe in (2) it should be (1-yi2)xia at the end?

Comment: I edited my question and removed the 100 to make it simpler

Comment: I added details of the three cases.  What didn't work?

Comment: Oh, my bad, it works actually, thanks so much. But what if epsilon = 0 ? I'm not sure to understand why we need this small positive tolerance?

Comment: The $\epsilon$ was to disambiguate the first two cases, but that is unnecessary. You can omit $y_i^1$ and constraint $(1)$.

Comment: I see! It is actually important, because i want to allow for xi - xia negative (no minimum SELL quantity, only minimum BUY quantity).

Comment: Edited again to allow $x_i-x_i^a$ negative, without $\epsilon$.